# <img> src attribute not changing using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hi guys I have made a JqueryUI simple slider,on certain value range I make Image URL and then try to change  src attribute.

There are four images I'm trying to change.

Check the [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/OwaisQureshi/GJKKe/3/).

I think the code is fine but its not working ,I dont know why ?

Comment: ...but the slider is not moving :) (FFox)

Comment: Take a look at your firebug/chrome console: `postRetrmntImage is not defined
$("#" + postRetrmntImage).attr('src', ImageName );`

Comment: Thank you guys I was using undefined variable :/ ,that's so stupid of me :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$("#" + postRetrmntImage).attr('src', ImageName );
```

to this:

```
$("#postRetrmntImage").attr('src', ImageName );
```

The problem is that youre not assigned any `postRetrmntImage` variable.

See update jsFiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GJKKe/5/)

Comment: Thank you dear ,I was using undefined variable :/ ,that's so stupid of me :-(

Answer (score 2):

Trying doing this:

```
 $("#" + postRetrmntImage.toString()).attr('src', ImageName );
```

Answer (score 2):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/8Sw5J/

**Explanation:** Please use this: `$("#" + sliderId).prop('src', ImageName );` since in your function you are passing the id as `sliderId.`

Also If I may suggest use `.prop` good read here: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Rest demo you can see how it works,

Hope this helps `:)`

**full code**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            makeSingleSliderWithImage('postRetrmntMnthlyPaymt', 0, 10000, 0, 500);
        }
        );
        function makeSingleSliderWithImage(sliderId, minimum, maximum, val, steps) {

            //Display label shud have a X appended
            $('#' + sliderId).slider(
                {
                    //range: 'min',
                    min: minimum,
                    max: maximum,
                    step: steps,
                    //starting values for silders
                    value: val,
                    slide: function (event, ui) {
                        //var ImageURL = "Images/";
                        //var ImageName = "";
                        //var ext = ".jpg";

                        if ((ui.value >= 0) && (ui.value <= 2000))//Basic: 0-2000
                            ImageName = "http://www.iconempire.com/icon-processor/icon40.gif";
                        else if ((ui.value >= 2500) && (ui.value <= 4500))//Moderate: 2500-4500
                            ImageName = "http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/14234829766434728.png";
                        else if ((ui.value >= 5000) && (ui.value <= 7000))//Comfortable: 5000-7000
                            ImageName = "http://www.iconempire.com/icon-processor/icon40.gif";
                        else if ((ui.value >= 7500) && (ui.value <= 10000))//Luxury:7500-10,000
                            ImageName = "Luxury";
                        //var fullURL = ImageURL + ImageName + ext;
                        //change Image URL
                        $("#" + sliderId).prop('src', ImageName ); //{ src: fullURL });

                        alert($("#" + sliderId).prop('src'));
                        //change Slider Value
                        $("#" + sliderId + "X").text(ui.value);
                    }
                }
            );
        }​
```

Answer (score 1):

Change line...

```
$("#" + postRetrmntImage).attr('src', ImageName );
```

to...

```
$("#postRetrmntImage").attr('src', ImageName );
```

Answer (score 1):

assign a value to `postRetrmntImage` then use `prop` instead of `attr` [see why prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
var postRetrmntImage="postRetrmntImage";
$("#" + postRetrmntImage).prop('src', ImageName );
```

Comment: can't I use $("#postRetrmntImage").prop('src', ImageName );

Comment: yes you can, i was trying to say, you can still use your variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#postRetrmntImage").attr('src', 'newimage.png');
```